# Javascript regex match returning a string with comma at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

Just as the title says...i'm trying to parse a string for example

2x + 3y

and i'm trying to get only the coefficients (i.e. 2 and 3)

I first tokenized it with space character as delimiter giving me "2x" "+" "3y"

then i parsed it again to this statement to get only the coefficients

```
var number = eqTokens[i].match(/(\-)?\d+/);
```

I tried printing the output but it gave me "2,"

why is it printing like this and how do i fix it? i tried using:

```
number = number.replace(/[,]/, "");
```

but this just gives me an error that number.replace is not a function

Comment: note: you may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705727/generate-syntax-tree-for-simple-math-operations).

Comment: The comma is because `number` is an array, with empty second element. In case if you used `alert` to output the value. Use `console.log` function for output into browser's console (opened by pressing F12 in most browsers)

Comment: why is it returning an array though?? I mean shouldn't it only match the number i.e if i'm trying to match "2x" shouldn't it only return 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
> "2x + 3y".match(/-?\d+(?=[A-Za-z]+)/g)
[ '2', '3' ]
```

The above regex would match the numbers only if it's followed by one or more alphabets.

Comment: for decimal numbers `"-2x + 3.5y".match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[A-Za-z]+)/g)`

Comment: I'm not that well-versed in the use of regex and the first thing that came up when I tried to perform this task was breaking it down as I did...Didn't know I can somehow get the number without getting the literal along with it as well

Answer (score 0):

Match is going to return an array of every match.  Since you put the optional negative in a parentheses, it's another capture group.  That capture group has one term and it's optional, so it'll return an empty match in addition to your actual match.

- Input 2x -> Your output: `[2,undefined]` which prints out as "2,"
- Input -2x -> Your output: `[2,-]`

Remove the parentheses around the negative.

This is just for the sake of explaining why your case is breaking but personally I'd use Avinash's answer.